# How can I print out the keys and values of a Python dictionary only 5 times?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
    for key, value in sorted(fdict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
        print(key,value)
```

I've got this much for just the printing right now, but I am unsure as to how to approach only printing the first five keys and values rather than all of them.

Comment: I second that. It's always good practice to provide feedback to people who spent time to help you out.

Answer (score 4):

Grab only the first 5 elements from the sorted list

```
for key, value in sorted(fdict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:5]:
    print(key,value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Did not realize that I could simply do that this easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `collections.Counter`:

```
for key, value in Counter(fdict).most_common(5):
    print(key, value)
```

Or `heapq.nlargest`:

```
for key, value in nlargest(5, fdict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `[:5]` to the end of the array (I removed the `.item()` to clean things up a bit):

```
for k in sorted(fdict,key=lambda x:fdict[x],reverse=True)[:5]:
    print(k,fdict[k])
```